# How to schedule a local notification if an action hasn't been made?

Tags: iphone, ios5, notifications

I would like to schedule a local notification to fire at 7pm everyday IF a certain condition is met (the user hasn't entered daily data).

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it up into 3 cases:

1. It's before 7pm, and the user **hasn't** entered their daily data yet
2. It's before 7pm, and the user **has** entered their daily data
3. It's after 7pm

In case 1, you set up a notification to go off at 7pm **today**, and then repeat every day.

In cases 2 and 3, you set up a notification to go off at 7pm **tomorrow**, and then repeat every day.

The code to create and schedule the notification looks like this:

```
UILocalNotification *dailyNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
dailyNotification.fireDate = nextReminderTime; // set this to 7pm today or tomorrow
dailyNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; 
dailyNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
dailyNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
dailyNotification.alertBody = @"You need to enter data for today.";
```

Of course, if you set up an alert for 7pm today, then the user opens the app and enters data before 7pm, the notification for today needs to be cancelled.

Alternatively (this is what I did in a similar situation), you can cancel all the notifications with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` and set them up again from scratch based on the application state every time the app is about to go into the background (i.e., in `UIApplication` `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. This is simpler since you don't have to think about what notifications you set up before.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling local notifications in iOS is fairly simple - Apple has a good example of how to do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

I'm assuming that the criteria to "enter daily data" is happening *in* your app, right? If so, then you'll basically just schedule local notifications for 7PM each day, and then if a user *does* enter daily data, you'll just cancel the notification for that day. I've found the local notification scheduling to be a bit finicky, so I would probably `cancelAllLocalNotifications` and then reschedule them all.

Keep in mind that apps are limited to only being able to have 64 scheduled local notifications at once. So theoretically, you could schedule 64 days into the future (since you're just having one notification per day). I'd be cautious with that though, since it may *really* annoy users. I'd maybe only do it for a few day or a week at a time, since if they aren't opening the app after a few reminders, they may have lost interest.

Comment: it's a good warning. Maybe I should give them the option to have daily reminders or weekly reminders

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that you can only schedule local notifications when your app is open. So if the user doesn't keep opening your app, you'll eventually run out of scheduled notifications and have no ability to schedule more. I guess that's a safeguard Apple's set against possible abuse.